# What is the Windows/cmd.exe equivalent of Linux/bash's $? -- the program exit/return code?

Tags: windows, cmd, return-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the application exit code from a Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line)

In Unix/bash, I can simply say:

> $ echo $?

to find out the return/exit code of a program, both from interactive and non-interactive shells.

Now, how can I do the equivalent in Windows/cmd.exe?

Answer (score 12):

Use "errorlevel", like this:

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO ERROR
```

The errorlevel command is a little peculiar; it returns true if the return code was equal to or **higher** than the specified errorlevel. You can also write

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO ERROR
```

[This page](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.html) is a good overview of how to use errorlevels in .bat files.

Comment: Be sure to check out the difference between ERRORLEVEL and %ERRORLEVEL%! http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx

Answer (score 6):

The equivalent is:

```
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Answer (score 2):

check for the ERRORLEVEL