# How can I set the exit code in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, exit-code

I want to set the exit code for my installation, this way I will know why the installation was aborted. I'm using Inno Setup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
[Code]
procedure ExitProcess(exitCode:integer);
  external 'ExitProcess@kernel32.dll stdcall';

procedure SomeEventHere();
begin
  if someerror then begin
    ExitProcess(9); //Your custom exit code
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This likely leaves temp files behind as the regular Inno Setup cleanup code won't run.

Answer (score 15):

From the Inno Setup Help document ([from the article "Setup Exit Codes"](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents)):

> Beginning with Inno Setup 3.0.3, the Setup program may return one of the following exit codes:
>
> **0** Setup was successfully run to completion.
>
> **1** Setup failed to initialize.
>
> **2** The user clicked Cancel in the wizard before the actual installation started, or chose "No" on the opening "This will install..." message box.
>
> **3** A fatal error occurred while preparing to move to the next installation phase (for example, from displaying the pre-installation wizard pages to the actual installation process). This should never happen except under the most unusual of circumstances, such as running out of memory or Windows resources.
>
> **4** A fatal error occurred during the actual installation process.
>
> Note: Errors that cause an Abort-Retry-Ignore box to be displayed are not fatal errors. If the user chooses Abort at such a message box, exit code `5` will be returned.
>
> **5** The user clicked Cancel during the actual installation process, or chose Abort at an Abort-Retry-Ignore box.
>
> **6** The Setup process was forcefully terminated by the debugger (Run | Terminate was used in the IDE).

You can easily check if the setup ran successfully by confirming that the exit code is `0`. Furthermore:

> Any non-zero exit code indicates that Setup was not run to completion.

To answer your question more specifically, you can determine the installation was canceled by observing exit code `2` or `5`.

If you wish to return a custom exit code when Inno would otherwise return `0`, you can define the following event function:

```
function GetCustomSetupExitCode: Integer;
```

From the help document ([from the article "Pascal Scripting: Event Functions"](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents)):

> `function GetCustomSetupExitCode: Integer;`
>
> Return a non zero number to instruct Setup to return a custom exit code. This function is only called if Setup was successfully run to completion and the exit code would have been `0`.

Comment: Tanks a lot. But I mean to set myself the exit code not to use the build-in  codes for my specific events. something like exit(88);

Comment: I see; I've revised my answer accordingly. Note that you can only define a custom exit code if Inno would have otherwise exited with `0`!

Comment: is there any way to do the opposite ? specifying to return `0` when inno would otherwise return `!0` ?

Comment: @v.oddou I don't believe that's possible, unless there's some way of intercepting the exit and forcing the process to end using lepe's answer.

Comment: there might be a way by wrapping the exe into another exe that always returns 0. but in the end for my own case, i just set the parent installer to ignore the return code. (otherwise when cancelling the child installer (made with inno) it would rollback everthing)

Comment: Where I can see these exit codes getting printed.I added a custom exit code and ran the application using command line but the application terminates without printing any such exit code.

Comment: If you're on Windows, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line). On other platforms, the previous exit code is simply returned in `$?`.

Answer (score 0):

Did have this same question and found a way to it:

```
[Code]
var CustomExitCode: integer;

procedure ExitProcess(exitCode:integer);
    external 'ExitProcess@kernel32.dll stdcall';

procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin
    if (CustomExitCode <> 0) then
    begin
        DelTree(ExpandConstant('{tmp}'), True, True, True);
        ExitProcess(CustomExitCode);
    end;
end;
```

And now at any point of your setup just set CustomExitCode to the code you want.
Example:

```
function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
    // Some check did fail, exiting with custom code
    CustomExitCode = -1;
    
    // Let's just close the setup
    Result := false;
end;
```

This way the setup will not terminate abruptly and you can customize the exit code no matter what state the wizard did exit.