# How to set "Error Return Code" for listing in MicrosoftStore with InnoSetup

Tags: windows, inno-setup

I want to use Inno Setup to list an exe file on MicrosoftStore.

When registering an app on the MicrosoftStore dashboard, I am asked to register an "Error Return Code" for the exe file.

The following image is a capture showing the list of them.

[image]

They are textualized as follows.

```
-Installation cancelled by user
-Application already exists
-Installation already in progress
-Disk space is full
-Reboot requiresd
-Network failure
-Package rejected during installation
-Installation successful
```

[Past StackOverFlow questions and answers about error codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013112/how-can-i-set-the-exit-code-in-inno-setup).
They were helpful, but in the case of InnoSetup error codes, the return code can be "2" or "5" if the user cancels from finding.
In contrast, there is only one registered entry for error codes in the Microsoft Store.

In such a case, is it necessary to customize the InnoSetup return code?
What code should I write in InnoSetup?

The following code is my InnoSetup code.

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "testApp"
#define MyAppVersion "1.00"
#define MyAppPublisher "My Company, Inc."
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "test.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application. Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{3D8E37F3-FB32-4AF9-8C64-58C37D542248}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={autopf}\{#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
; Uncomment the following line to run in non administrative install mode (install for current user only.)
;PrivilegesRequired=lowest
OutputDir=C:\Users\taichi\Desktop
OutputBaseFilename=mysetup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\taichi\Desktop\dist\test\test.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\taichi\Desktop\dist\test\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Comment: Cannot you use the *"Add More"* link to add both 2 and 5?

Comment: It is possible! I hadn't noticed that, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the *"Add More"* link is there for the very reason:
To allow you to add both `2` and `5`.