# ERRORLEVEL inside IF

Tags: batch-file, errorlevel

Just stumbled into a weird thing with `%ERRORLEVEL%` and wanted to see if anyone knows why and if there's a way to fix it. Essentially, it seems as if commands executed inside if statements don't set the `%ERRORLEVEL%` variable. The `ERRORLEVEL` (as in `IF ERRORLEVEL 1`, which is different from `IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1` ) check seems to still work fine though, so I can probably work around it, but it would still be nice to be able to print the error level. For debugging or whatever.

```
@echo off
Set TESTVAR=1

tasklist | find /I "IsntRunning.exe" > NUL
echo OUTSIDE_IF %ERRORLEVEL%

ThisWillSetErrorLevelTo9009ieNotRecognizedCommand

tasklist | find /I "IsntRunning.exe" > NUL
echo OUTSIDE_IF %ERRORLEVEL%

ThisWillSetErrorLevelTo9009ieNotRecognizedCommand

IF %TESTVAR% EQU 1 (
    Set ERRORLEVEL=
    tasklist | find /I "IsntRunning.exe" > NUL
    echo INSIDE_IF  ERRORLEVEL %ERRORLEVEL%
    
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        echo INSIDE_IF2  ERRORLEVEL GREQ 1 %ERRORLEVEL%
    )
    IF ERRORLEVEL 2 (
        echo INSIDE_IF2  ERRORLEVEL GREQ 2 %ERRORLEVEL%
    )
    IF ERRORLEVEL 3 (
        echo INSIDE_IF2  ERRORLEVEL GREQ 3 %ERRORLEVEL%
    )
)

tasklist | find /I "IsntRunning.exe" > NUL
echo OUTSIDE_IF ERRORLEVEL %ERRORLEVEL%

@echo on
```

Putting that in a batch file and running it produces this output:

> C:\Users\username\Documents\work>test.bat
> OUTSIDE_IF 1
> 'ThisWillSetErrorLevelTo9009ieNotRecognizedCommand' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> OUTSIDE_IF 1
> 'ThisWillSetErrorLevelTo9009ieNotRecognizedCommand' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> INSIDE_IF  ERRORLEVEL 9009
> INSIDE_IF2  ERRORLEVEL GREQ 1 9009
> OUTSIDE_IF ERRORLEVEL 1

**Relevant articles:**

- [ERRORLEVEL is not %ERRORLEVEL%](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080926-00/?p=20743)
- [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files (69576)](https://hwiegman.home.xs4all.nl/msdos/69576.htm)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try using `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at the start of your batch file, and `!ERRORLEVEL!` inside your `IF`.  This seems to work for me:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
dir nul
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
if .1.==.1. (
  urklbkrlksdj - not a command
  echo %ERRORLEVEL%
  echo !ERRORLEVEL!
)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. That works and even explains it. For reference, some links I found about it: http://batcheero.blogspot.com/2007/06/how-to-enabledelayedexpansion.html | http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/setlocal.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 2):

`if errorlevel` works without delayed expansion but works in manner similar to

`if %errorlevel% <= Some_Value ...` :

```
@echo off

::sets errorlevel to 0
(call )
if "1" == "1" (
    rem sets errorlevel to 5
    cmd /c exit 5
    if errorlevel 4 echo this will be printed
    if errorlevel 5 echo this will be printed
    rem :::: you can use this ::::::::::::::
    if errorlevel 5 if not errorlevel 6 echo this will be printed ONLY when the errorlevel is 5
    rem :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    if errorlevel 6 echo this will not be printed

)
```