# return code of console application

Tags: c#, c++, command-prompt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the application exit code from a Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line)

I have a console application. It will be executed from command prompt. It will return either 0 or 1 from main method. How can I know that what value is returned by the application?

Comment: it will return 1/0 as exit code or will write out to the console?

Comment: Have a look at this [stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're on Windows (C# tag)

```
echo %errorlevel%
```

Comment: If you're on Unix, it's `echo $?`.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the command line app with the Process class in C#:

- if you look for the exitcode: process.ExitCode
- if you need to read what the app has written to the console: process.StandardError.ReadToEnd() or process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()

If you need this in C++ since you gave that TAG too, I cannot help you much.

You should choose one of those tags, or have you put unrelated tags into the question?