# What is the syntax for executing a Perl script and capturing its exit value in Windows batch script?

Tags: perl, batch-file, errorlevel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the application exit code from a Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line)

The Perl script that I'm calling inside batch returns a `1`, `2`, or `3`. What's the syntax for calling this perl sript with an argument 829, and capturing the script's exit code?

```
 Perl.exe listMembership.pl 829 in cmd.exe

 @echo off
 set retVal=Perl.exe listMembership.pl 829
 echo %retVal%
```

Comment: @KeithThompson - it was 24% just less than hour ago...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the output of `if /?` on the command line. Without `cmd` extensions, the lowest common denominator batch script would be something along the lines of:

```
@echo off
Perl.exe listMembership.pl 829
if errorlevel 4 goto error
if errorlevel 3 goto exit3
if errorlevel 2 goto exit2
if errorlevel 1 goto exit1
if errorlevel 0 goto exit0

:error
echo:Unexpected exit code %ERRORLEVEL%
goto end

:exit3
echo:Forbnicate
goto end

:exit2
echo:Colormaticate
goto end

:exit1
echo:Motorcade
goto end

:exit0
echo:Is this really success?
goto end

:end
echo:Done
```

Keep in mind, `errorlevel` checks have to be in descending order because:

```
ERRORLEVEL number Specifies a true condition if the last program run
                returned an exit code equal to or greater than the number
                specified.
```