# exit status of a program

Tags: c++, c

I came into a situation where I have to take the exit status of my program that is the number returned by `exit()` function.

in LINUX,  using `$?` command i got the status. Is there any other method to get this status which can work in windows too ?

one other thing I noticed is that if we pass a negative number to `exit()` function it crashes my IDE and `$?` command not able to give status in this case too. I checked `exit()` function its reference says we can pass a integer.

Comment: See related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line

Comment: Note that, in general, the only portable return values are `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`, defined in `<stdlib.h>` and `<cstdlib>`.

Comment: @PeteBecker, 0 is also portable IIRC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Program return values mean different things on different operating systems. On Unix-y systems, only values 0-255 are valid (1 unsigned byte). Note this means negative values are not allowed, and may be the cause of your IDE problems. FreeBSD introduced a load of specific meanings in [`sysexits.h`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysexits&sektion=3), and while this certainly exists on Linux distributions I've used, the only real universally accepted one is `0` for success and non-`0` for failure. As `Pete Becker` points out, `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are standard defined macros (`0` and `1` respectively on Unix-y platforms, but implementation defined).

On windows, you get a 32 bit signed integer (negatives are allowed, don't know if they mean anything). Again, `0` is success, and other values mean [various things](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Like `echo $?`, you can use `echo %errorlevel%` to see the last program's exit code in the console.

Also note that my `N3337` (draft very close to C++11 standard) says at `section 3.6.1 paragraph 5`:

> If control reaches the end of `main` without encountering a `return`
>   statement, the effect is that of executing `return 0;`