# Wrong exit value from external program

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec

I'm trying to read exit value from external program but it's always 0.

```
String command = ("cmd  /c start /wait "+ Script[0]);                          
Process exec = runtime.exec(command);                   
int waitFor = exec.waitFor();
System.out.println(exec.exitValue);     //always 0   
System.out.println(waitFor); //always 0
```

Program is used for programming modules and I need to  know if there were any error's.

How to get the application exit value?

Comment: You're getting the exit value from cmd, not your program.

Comment: Tips: 1) Change `String command = ("cmd  /c start /wait "+ Script[0]);` to `String[] command = ("cmd", "/c", "start", "/wait ", Script[0]);` 2) Use a [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to create the `Process`. 3) Implement all the tips in [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

Comment: What is stopping you from running `Script[0]` directly?

Answer (score 1):

The program you're actually running is the `cmd` program, not whatever you're running under that.

See [How do I get the application exit code from a Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line) for how to extract the underlying exit code.

Comment: I have another question.I use  command line program stk500.exe ,so i should use "cmd" right ?