# SVN can't commit to svn not asking for username password

Tags: windows, git, svn, ubuntu, repository

I just installed subversion on my ubuntu and made first repository
now its accessible with `http://mylanip/mywebsite` or my lan ip
I tried to checkout with windows machine on lan and it checked out successfully without asking username and password
it can't commit changes and showing error "target machine actively refused it"
please help me sorting out this problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Check permissions on the repository folder.

Comment: "target machine actively refused it" is not an error from the Subversion code, can you provide the exact error message you're receiving.  It will also usually include an error code.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the "svn commit" from the command line:

```
svn commit -m "My message"
echo $?
```

The `$?` variable is the exit code of the last command in Bash. This exit code might give you more information if you search Google for "svn commit fails with exit code XXXX"

If using the Windows command line, the exit code is a little more difficult to obtain ([How do I get the application exit code from a Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line))

Comment: Well, i already shifted to windows tortoise svn without password verification, it works fine though don't need password protect now as its finalized to be on lan only, thanks btw :)