# How to see returned value from char type main()

Tags: c, char, stdio

I make a C program that returns char type value;

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *main(){
        return "## returned ##";
}
```

I get no message on standard out when I run it.

Any good way to see returned value on standard out without driver program?

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line

Comment: That is not how main works.

Comment: The return type of main () is not char*, but int. That's what the operating system expects. So what you are trying is not going to work, and you won't be able to make it work.

Comment: Just to make sure: You can't return any pointers to some allocated memory (unless in some very rare circumstances). The memory will be deallocated once the program closes, even if you don't deallocate it properly. Same is true for const string literals (like in your example). You can only pass integers (or you could possibly "encode" a short string in an integer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in C, `main()` function **always** has to return an `int`.
That `int` value is returned to the operating system to indicate how did the program exit (successful termination, error during run) etc ....

In Windows, the value returned by `main()` is stored in a  pseudo environment variable named `errorlevel`. to check for the its value you can simple use `echo`.

```
echo the program terminated with exit code %errorlevel%
```

a successful run is *usually* indicated by the value `0`. *
that is why you see the traditional `return 0;` in all `C` Programs.

<sub>* As mentioned in the comment this is not a standard nor a requirement, it just the convention</sub>

Comment: **a successful run is indicated by the value `0`.** As far as I know that's far from being standardized. It's just a general assumption.

Comment: @Mario: right that is not a standard, but I guess it is the convention    , should I remove that ?

Comment: No, it's fine, just add "usually" or something similar. It really depends on what your program is supposed to return.

Comment: Clarifying that compilers are allowed to support other return types. `int` *must* be supported on all compilers; other types may or may not be supported.

Comment: `return 0;` is guaranteed to return a code to the OS that indicates success, this may actually be non-zero on an OS that expects programs to return `0` for failure and `1` for success.