# Atlassian SourceTree custom action contrast

Tags: eclipse, windows, git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

After checking out a new branch, I wanted to stop tracking of files like .classpath via Atlassian SourceTree (Version 1.4.0.0). I created a custom action with the details below:

[image]

Then, from the "Working Copy changes" panel, I selected a file, right-clicked on it and tried to execute "assume unchanged" custom command. However, I got this totally "scrimpy" error message:

[image]

I copied the full command in the error message above and tried to execute it from the command line:[image]

Interestingly, it worked.

Can someone tell me why this custom action didn't work at first place via right clicking and selecting from the menu?

Comment: Which version of SourceTree are you using, Windows or OS X?

Comment: @Cupcake I'm using Windows version, 1.5.2.0

Comment: Check the exit code that the command returns (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/334890/254041).

Comment: I thought it involved a lawsuit, when I read controversy :D

Answer (score 2):

This is interesting. I just noticed this issue on my own setup when a previously working git-based command now no longer worked. I assume something has changed in the more recent version of SourceTree. I believe the issue is now invoked commands won't get the complete environment setup configured just as one might expect when opening a terminal from SourceTree. The `Completed with errors` message is a result of the command not being found.

For my own setup, I work around this issue by building my custom actions with the `cmd` process. For example:

- Caption: Full Index Patch for Selected Commit
- Script to run: cmd

With parameters:

```
/c %LOCALAPPDATA%\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\bin\sh.exe --login -i -c 'git format-patch --full-index -1 $SHA'
```

Another example:

- Caption: Full Index Patch for Working Index
- Script to run: cmd

With parameters:

```
/c %LOCALAPPDATA%\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\bin\sh.exe --login -i -c ^"git diff --full-index --cached > patch.diff^"
```

(these examples assume you're using the embedded Git in SourceTree)

Using SourceTree 1.6.12 and Git 1.8.3.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `$FILE` represents the full complete path of the file you selected.
It seems to be presented that way in "[Custom actions – more power to you](http://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2012/02/08/custom-actions-more-power-to-you/)" (Feb. 2012, when custom actions were introduced to Atlassian Source Tree 1.3+).

If that is the case, using `$FILE` instead of `C:/Repository/$FILE` should be enough.

Comment: I double checked my paths, $FILE represents the relative path of the selected file, that's why I added the repository path as a prefix. Additionally, I already mentioned that the command (which appears in the error message) generated by the custom action works when I copy and paste it to the command line. That's the strange thing!

Comment: Ok. Can you try it with $ FILE alonz though, just for testing?

Comment: before trying with the repositoryPath+$FILE, I already tested with $FILE alone and it didn't work. To clarify, how can a command work from command line while it doesn't work via the UI?

Comment: @Juvanis It says "completed with errors, see above": is there any error message?

Comment: that's why I called the error message as "scrimpy" in my post. the error message is just that :)

Comment: And just to test, would a `git` / `log -1 $REPO/$FILE` work better?

Comment: And did you select the "Show full output" option in that dialog box?

Comment: "Show full output" was selected, sir. don't worry, I have done all trivial things.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got some custom actions in Windows with SourceTree Custom Action:

## git stash + pull + unstash in Windows

Script to run: `cmd`
Parameters: `/c %LOCALAPPDATA%\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\bin\sh.exe -c -e 'alias git=/c/Users/%username%/AppData/Local/Atlassian/SourceTree/git_local/cmd/git.exe; git stash; git pull --rebase; git stash pop'`

This handles if you have multiple versions of git installed, and exits early if it fails mid-way.

## git stash + pull + unstash in MacOS

The rough equivalent in MacOS looks like:

Script to run: `/path/to/stash_unstash.sh`
Parameters: `$REPO`

stash_unstash.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd $1
git stash && git pull --rebase && git stash pop
```

Answer (score 0):

macOS - Custom Action:

Script to run: `/bin/bash`

Parameters:

`cd $REPO && git stash && git pull && git stash pop`

`cd $REPO && git stash && git pull --rebase && git stash pop`