# Is there a way that we can tell whether cmake --build is successful or not?

Tags: jenkins, cmake

CMake can not only create projects on different platforms but also can build the project. For example, using `cmake --build` command can build the created projects on different platforms. However, the big problem is that invoking this command will not return a value, which will tell whether the built project is successful or not. In many cases, we desperately need know this information. For example, when we use Jenkins to automatically built the project, we need a way to tell Jenkins whether the built project is successful or not. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the application exit code from a Windows command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line)

Comment: It returns exit code on my machine.

Comment: @Peter - its not clear to me this is a Windows question. There's no Windows tag. Jenkins is Java so it should run anywhere. Where did you surmise this was a Windows question?