# Checking exit code returned by a python function

Tags: python-2.7, windows-shell

I have written a python function

```
def foo():
    if A:
        do something
    if B:
        exit(-1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo()
```

Is there any way to check the exit code returned by foo function? I am running it from windows shell.

Comment: Do you mean from the command line?

Comment: yes, from command line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check the exit code, you look at the variable `$?` (in sh/bash/csh/etc.).  Let's say your script is in a file foo.py.

```
$ ./foo.py
$ echo $?  # Prints 0 on success, -1 on failure.
```

This is not specific to python, BTW.  It is true for all programs that return an exit code.

---

The exit code is not from the `foo` function, but rather from the `sys.exit()` function.  If the program exits due to an exception, it has exit code 1.  If you pass a number to `sys.exit()`, it exits with that exit code.  Otherwise, it has exit code 0.

---

For Windows shell check out this answer: [How do I get the application exit code from a Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line)

Comment: Actually it prints 0 or 255! Exit code in Unix systems is a 16 bit wide value and the returned exit code is the upper 8 bits of it (lower 8 bit states if core dump has been created and the signal number, if any). `python -c 'exit(-1)'; echo $?` prints 255.