# Simple check of PHPUnit result

Tags: php, phpunit

I want to to glue PHPUnit with other command tools and I need a simple way to check if the tests passed or failed.

Somethings like

```
phpunit path_to_folder_containing_the_test
```

Would return "ok" if all passed or "failed" if any test failed.

[So I can simply check for "ok" and "failed" values from other tools]

Comment: Hi @Alex if mine or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 4):

I have a very simply shell script that capture the exit code like:

```
>phpunit TestOk.php
>echo $?
0
```

and

```
>phpunit TestKo.php
>echo $?
1
```

Hope this help

Comment: First what you posted seems like a bash variable (I'm on a Windows machine), secondly the output of phpunit is verbose regardless of your test output, so in short it does not work

Comment: Hi @Alex I collapse the (irrilevant?) output of the phpunit but i confirm that is work. I suggest you to give a try and to capture the exit code that is something like an `error_level` variable, check something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line

Answer (score 1):

In your batch file, look for ERRORLEVEL

```
@echo off
call PHPUNIT.bat
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto Fail
if ERRORLEVEL 0 goto Pass
:Pass
echo PHPUnit Successfully Executed
goto End
:Fail
echo PHPUnit Failed
goto End
:End
```

Change the `echo` statements to do whatever you wanted. If PHPUnit is returning other error codes (255 and down) then you can continue to use `if ERRORLEVEL 255` to control functionality on that specific return code.