# PHPUnit - Bash Script Output to Variable

Tags: php, bash, phpunit

I'm trying to capture the output of my test suite from PHPUnit to determine whether a failure occurred.  However, when I attempt to store the output in a bash variable, the variable is always empty:

```
PHPUNIT_RESULT=`vendor/bin/phpunit`

if [ -z "$PHPUNIT_RESULT" ]; then
        echo "something there!
fi
```

However, the variable always seems to be empty.

EDIT: Sample output

```
PHPUnit 3.4.5 by Sebastian Bergmann.

......F.......F

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 8.00Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) MyTest::testTemp
Failed asserting that <boolean:false> is true.

/path/to/myTest.php:68

FAILURES!
Tests: 4, Assertions: 5, Failures: 1, Incomplete: 1.
```

Comment: To start with, generally speaking, using backticks to perform command substitution in `bash` is discouraged. Use the `$(...)` syntax instead. In either case, what's the expected output of `vendor/bin/phpunit`?

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz thanks for the info.  I've also tried it with `$()` and had the same results.  I've updated the question with a sample output.  It is multi-line output.

Comment: have you already see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164652/simple-check-of-phpunit-result/29165024#29165024)?

Comment: Don't forget as well that the `-z` operator checks for an empty string - so, if you print "Something there!", it actually means you're getting output!

Comment: @Matteo thanks for that link, it lead to some useful results

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if there's any test failure, phpunit will exit with a non-zero status. you can check this with the `$?` variable.

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit /path/to/myTest.php

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "failed test"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Thats exactly what I ended up doing