# how to do an if statement based on wget retrieved content

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wget

I have a batch file with this command

```
wget www.example.com || powershell.exe command
```

example.com returns 1 or 0 as content-type plaintext

But whether it returns 1 or 0 powershell.exe command doesn't get run. I expect a response of 0 to lead to the powershell command being executed

The length of the response is 1 as expected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the application exit code from a Windows command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

If `wget` utility returns `errorlevel` *exit code* `0` or `1`, you should use

```
wget www.example.com && powershell.exe command
```

or

```
wget www.example.com
if %errorlevel% equ 0 powershell.exe command
```

Resources:

- `||` and `&&` [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)
- `IF` [Conditionally perform a command](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- `errorlevel` [exit code](http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html)

*Sidenote*: In prime version of my answer, in doubt about `wget` utility output (**displays** `0` or `1` *only*, or **returns** that exit code?), there was an attempt for the first case (display) with next resource: `for /F` [Loop against the results of a command](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html). Being led by [l'L'l](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499581/lll)'s comment, I removed this part :)