# How to examine return value of wget in windows

Tags: windows, cmd, wget

*How do I convert the below code into CMD line code for windows?*

```
r=`wget -q www.someurl.com`
if [ $r -ne 0 ]
  then echo "Not there"
  else echo "OK"
fi
```

Comment: you ask this question in  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290564/how-to-do-an-if-statement-based-on-wget-retrieved-content) ! see my answer in this link `$?` that exist in bash for check in cmd you should check `if errorlevel`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the application exit code from a Windows command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this:

```
wget.exe -q www.someurl.com
if errorlevel 1 (
   echo not there
) ELSE (
    echo ok
)
```

the error can be printed with

```
    echo Failure  is %errorlevel%
```

Answer (score 0):

Using cmd's short-circuit `&&` and `||` operators:

```
wget.exe -q www.someurl.com && (
  echo OK
) || (
  echo Not there
)
```

If the statements are short, you can make this into a one-liner

```
wget.exe -q www.someurl.com && ( echo OK ) || ( echo Not there )
```

This method only notes if the exit code is zero or nonzero.  If you need the actual exit code, use the `if` statements in Stuart Siegler's answer.