# Run git bash script in Windows 7/64bit

Tags: git, bash

I am trying to run a git bash file in Windows 7, 64-bit. The file is below. The command is:

```
git test-bash
```

When the command is entered, there is a pause of no more than a second, then the prompt returns. There is no output to the terminal and no file created. What am I doing wrong?

file git-test-bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
# start
printf "test-bash-printf"
echo "test-bash-echo"
echo "test-bash-echo-to_file" > /d/Users/joeuser/bin/file.txt
```

Comment: `git test-bash` != `git-test-bash` unless you are writing that as a git subcommand. Are you sure your script is being run? Where does the script live? What is the exit status of `git test-bash`?

Comment: No I am not sure if the script is being run, hence the question. My understanding is that in order to run a file named "git-any-text-here" one enters the command as "git any-text-here" (without the space after git). The script is in /d/Users/joeuser/bin/ and this directory is on the PATH.How do I determine the exit status?

Comment: @AlLelopath,  The exit code of the last command is available in `$?` (see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line). If you append  `-x` to the first line (`#!/bin/bash -x`) you get a trace of the issued commands and their result, which can be helpfull to debug the code.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested git-test-bash in a regular DOS session, or in a shell session (calling `c:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.5.1-64-bit\git-bash.exe`).

It does work (except you might want to add '`\n`' in order to put the `printf` in its own line)

```
#!/bin/bash
# start
printf "test-bash-printf\n"
echo "test-bash-echo"
echo "test-bash-echo-to_file" > /C/Users/VonC/prog/file.txt
```

You only have to make sure `%PATH%` (meaning in DOS session) includes the folder where `git-test-bash` is.

Output:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\b2d>git test-bash
test-bash-printf
test-bash-echo
```

Or in bash shell session:

```
vonc@bigvonc MINGW64 ~/prog/b2d (master)
$ git test-bash
test-bash-printf
test-bash-echo
```

Try it with a [recent git-for-windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) though.
I used the latest 2.5.1.