# Very basic git batch in Windows 7

Tags: windows, git, bash

**Synopsis**

Pass arguments to git bash using a .bat file

OR

Use git some other way by running a batch file.

**Disclaimer**

There are a lot of answers to similar questions out there, but having tried and failed most or all of them, I hope you don't smack me with a DUPLICATE stamp at first sight.

**My system**

Windows 7, 64 bit

git version 1.9.4.msysgit.2

**The challenge**

I want to rationalize my workflow from navigating to a number of git repos and running `git status`, `git add --all` etc, to simply run a batch.

Other posts certainly suggests it's possible. I think most of them use Unix, but [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203723/how-do-i-write-a-batch-file-which-opens-the-gitbash-shell-and-runs-a-command-in) at least got me up and running on Windows so I could test it out. However, I'm having the same problems as OP in that post when it comes to passing the commands to the git bash, and to a complete beginner like me it seems a bit complicated to use the suggestions from @Erik further down in the same post if you want to include more commands in the work flow.

Following the suggestions from @inf3rno in the same post, it seems I'm able to change folders but not able to use git commands like this:

```
set bash=C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\bash.exe
"%bash%" --login -i -c "exec "%1""
cd c:\repos\research
git status
pause
```

Does anyone have suggestions as to how I can change the code above to get it working?

And by the way, what's the deal with `#!bin\bash` from other posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511223/run-git-bash-script-in-windows-7-64bit)? I assumed I had to use `#!Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\bash`, but I had no luck with that either...

Anyway, thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, uninstall git 1.9.4 ([msygit](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/), which is now obsolete): [git-for-windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git) will offer a [much recent bash (2013 vs. 2005)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309).

Simply unzip [`PortableGit-2.6.1-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.6.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.6.1-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want, add `C:\path\PortableGit-2.6.1-64-bit\bin` to your `%PATH%` and you are good to go.

Second, [inf3rno's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9286963/6309) is about executing any bash script (`"%bash%" --login -i -c "exec "%1""`: the %1 is the path/name of the bash script to be executed)

The right shebang to use in your bash scripts would be #!/bin/bash (see "[What is the preferred Bash shebang?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10376206/6309)")

With the latest git 2.6, that would be:

```
c:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.6.1-64-bit\bin\bash.exe --login -i -c "exec ./myscript"
```

Since that folder is supposed to be in your %PATH%:

```
bash --login -i -c "exec ./myscript"
```

With `myscript` being a file using Unix-style eol (LF), not Windows-style (CRLF)

Note also that any bash script (even on Windows) called git-myscript can be directly called with:

```
git myscript
```

I described in 2012 another approach in "[Running a batch file in git shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11273633/6309)" for executing git command.
But for a pure bash script, you will want to go with `bash --login -i -c "exec ./myscript"`.

For writing bash scripts with unix eol style, you can choose various editor from [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), [SublimeText 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) or [Atom.io](https://atom.io/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Here's what I've done so far:

1. Removed git 1.9.4 successfully
2. Installed PortableGit-2.6.1-64-bit.7z.exe to the folder c:\prgs\git
3. Added c:\prgs\git\bin to %PATH%
4. Tried to run a bath containing  `#!/bin/bash
cd /c/repos/research
git status
pause`  But I'm getting an error saying #!/bin/bash is not recognized. Am I missing something embarrasingly obvious, or am I approaching the whole thing the wrong way? Edit: I'm trying to make the comment look better by editing the mini-Markdown formatting.

Comment: @123apd how exactly did you run your bash script? I have tested the `bash --login -i -c "exec ./myscript"` approach myself, and it works just fine.

Comment: I tried runnint it from a .bat file (now something tells me that's a complete face plant)

Comment: @123apd yes, a .bat would invoke the Windows CMD shell. The line I mention above is made to execute a bash script (again, make sure to write that bash script in an editor using unix-style eol)

Comment: Ok, I was under the impression that having git for windows installed, adding the correct path to %PATH%, and then running a .bat file including the #!/bin/bash part somehow would enable me to pass git commands through the Windows CMD shell. I guess I'm going to have to go through the details again and get a better understanding of the whole thing.

Comment: @123apd Indeed: any bash script must be executed in a bash shell (even if it starts with `#!/bin/bash`). Hence my suggestion to call that bash in order to execute said script. `bash --login -i -c "exec ./myscript"`.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as to which editor to use? And if it's relevant, what is the last part of your myscript filename?

Comment: My first step of a better understanding of this whole thing was to focus on your suggestions on other posts. After following your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229619/running-a-batch-file-in-git-shell) i got things working exactly as I was hoping by editing your `test.bat`. I have to admit I don't know exactly why, but it works like a charm, and results from for example `git status` are displayed directly in the CMD shell. Thank you for all your help and hints! Both here and elsewhere.

Comment: @123apd the bash command will run any filnename (no extension required). A Notepad++, SublimeText or Atom.io are all capable of handling bash script with unix eol.

Comment: @123apd I have edited the answer to add those links, by the way.