# How to force phantomjs to consider exit code

Tags: phantomjs

I am learning about `PhantomJS` and immediatelly found problem.
I want to test `exit code` but seems that phantomjs ignores it. Here is my code:

```
//say hello
console.log("Hello world");

//exit PhantomJS
phantom.exit(1);
```

In given example I expect to see message "FAIL" in the console but whatever I pass output is the same .. only "Hello world" is displaued.

I am using windows 7 with phantomjs version 2.1.1

Comment: How do you test for the exit code?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I am testing visually. Expecting to see "FAIL" in console or something similar pointing that something went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS doesn't print anything if it is exited regardless of exit code. If you want to write to the console in case of an error, you can use a simple `console.log("FAIL")` before calling `phantom.exit(1)`.

On Windows you can also check the exit code of the previously executed program:

```
$ echo %errorlevel%
0
$ phantomjs
> phantom.exit(42)
$ echo %errorlevel%
42
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/334879/1816580) for more information on the exit code.