# Django how do I get a command to execute when all tests pass?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to have a function fire when all the tests pass.

trying to do something along the lines of:

```
call(["say", "all tests have passed Dave"])
```

Comment: What test runner do you use?

Comment: just the generic one that comes with django.  I have a tests.py file that imports TestCase

Comment: Can you use the return code of `./manage.py test`?

Answer (score 1):

When you run `./manage.py test`, the exit status of the command is zero (success) if all tests have passed and non-zero (failure) otherwise. In Unix/Linux, you can do this:

```
./manage.py test  &&  echo "All tests have passed"
```

For Windows, [see another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line).