# no eslint output

Tags: node.js, eslint

This might be a dumb question so sorry in advance. I have gotten this result when I run eslint on my file.

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/.bin/eslint
  0:0  warning  File ignored by default. Use "--ignore-pattern '!node_modules/*'" to override

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)
```

so I include --ignore-pattern to get rid of that warning however I get no response back. Does this mean my file has no lint warnings or errors?

```
jafar70:~/workspace (master) $ eslint  --ignore-pattern ./node_modules/.bin/eslint index.js
jafar70:~/workspace (master) $
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when eslint returns no output, it means there were no issues found.

Try running `echo $?` to see the last commands exit code. It should be `0` if successful. Anything else is an error. (or for Windows use [errorlevel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line))

You could also test it by intentionally violating one of your rules and running it again.