# Stop Jenkins job if error occur

Tags: powershell, batch-file, jenkins

I am running a script on a remote server (windows) using Jenkins:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName myserver -ScriptBlock { D:\DeployScript\myscript.bat } -credential $Cred -ErrorAction Stop
```

inside this "myscript.bat" i running a psexec command:

```
psexec -i -h -u myserver\Administrator -p mypassword {mycommands}
```

how can i tell Jenkins to stop if an error occur on "myscript.bat"

(i must using Psexec because the script require interactive desktop)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In powershell you can get the exit code of the last command using the automatic variable `$lastexitcode`, so try something like this:

```
if ($lastexitcode -ne 0) { exit 1 }
```

or even better:

```
exit $lastexitcode
```

Comment: Thanks ! i will try it.Does the powershell script will know that the psexec threw an error? i dont need to :forward" it?

Comment: probably this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line @abovebeyond15