# How to pass an environment variable to another process?

Tags: c++, batch-file

Here is an example in source code.

When I use

```
SetEnvironmentVariable("key","false");
```

and run the compiled file inside a batch file

```
myfile.exe 
echo %key% 
pause
```

my environment variable is undefined.

How can I change this so that it will output false?

Comment: A solution is that the environment variables with their values are written by the executable into a file, for example the folder for temporary files, which is read or executed next by the batch file. For example the executable creates `"%TEMP%\MyFileEnvs.bat"` with the line `set "key=false"` and other __SET__ command lines and the batch file contains as next line after calling the executable the line `call "%TEMP%\MyFileEnvs.bat" & del "%TEMP%\MyFileEnvs.bat"`.

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables can only be passed in one direction: from parent to child processes. In your case, you are trying to go the inverse path, which is extremely difficult.

Instead, you can use a return value of your program

```
int main(int, char**)
{
    // ...

    return 123; // some error code maybe
}
```

to easily communicate with the parent process, but this is limited to integers and you might want to respect existing conventions on the meaning of these return values. Another possibility  is to let the main program write to the standard output, which can then be parsed within the batch file for further processing.

Comment: Thanks, this really helps!Also how could i tell what the return value is in batch? Using %errorlevel%?

Comment: Seems to be the way to go, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/334879/9593596).

Comment: I would change _"which is impossible for the sake of safety"_ by _"which is extremely difficult"_...

Comment: Thanks, I adjusted that. Can you give me a hint how this could be achived in theory?