# Is there a way to stop a jmeter test if you get an error from a step?

Tags: jmeter

Let's say, I want to test an application with Jmeter. How ever, i want the test to stop if one step get higher than 50% errors or if the step is getting an 404 error.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use [AutoStop Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-autostop-listener-how-to-do-it-right) plugin which can stop your test basing on various criteria including custom ones coming i.e. from the [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)

   [image: JMeter Auto Stop Listener]

   Auto Stop Listener can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
2. You can use [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper for JMeter tests. It has flexible and powerful [Pass/Fail Criteria](http://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) subsystem which not only stops the test, but also returns [non-zero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line) so you can use it from scripts or a [Continuous Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) tool to mark the build as unstable or failed.

Comment: Well, that was exactly what I was looking for! Really appreciate your help :) @Dmitri T