# Using batch script: starting java -> get parameter -> start .exe

Tags: java, batch-file, parameters

How can I start an .exe file with parameters I get from an output of an .jar file.

I know how I can start my java program with parameters within a batch:

```
java -jar javaProgram.jar %1 %2 %3 %4
```

But how can I get a result of the java code for example "Yes" or "No" to start a new program .exe within the same batch?

I this even possible?

Comment: Not your exact use case, but [this reference may be useful](https://gist.github.com/crowcoder/613104a403cec7f503fc#file-webjobjar-cs)

Comment: If the output is simply yes and no, you should consider using return codes. See this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line

Comment: Thanks for your information. I am using the ProcessBuilder now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exe must always return an int
use error level:

```
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    REM do something here to address the error
  )
```

[See more here](https://superuser.com/questions/194662/how-to-check-the-exit-code-of-the-last-command-in-batch-file)

To exec exe file in java use this code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("your exe file here ", "myArg1", "myArg2");
pb.directory(new File("your path here"));
Process p = pb.start();
```

[see more about ProcessBuilder here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Comment: I thought this was a question about batch

Comment: @user648026 Thanks, this solved my problem. I am starting the exe from my java program with the ProcessBuilder.