# How to detect if qt application exited normally or not?

Tags: qt, qcoreapplication

I have a Qt application (non-GUI) running. I want to know the state in which my application exited so I can either restart it or mark it as completed successfully. Think of it as a simple shell script that wants to know this.

I'm using `QCoreApplication::exit(errorCode)` to exit the application but I'm not sure how and where to read this value.

Comment: I don't think there's anything Qt specific about this, so you might check this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line

Comment: @MrEricSir You would still need to return the errorCode from main()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QCoreApplication::exit(errorCode)` exits the event loop with a return value of `errorCode`.

```
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    return a.exec();
}
...
a.exit(errorCode)
```

returns `errorCode` from the application

If you are using *bash* as a shell you can find the exit code of the last application in $?

```
bash$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: I think I got the answer. QCoreApplication.exit() would only exit event loop and doesn't directly reflect the application status. On calling QCoreApplication::exec() it waits for the exit() method and return the code passed on to exit(errorCode). So I needed to return the code returned by QCoreApplication::exec(). If you can add this part to your answer, I'll accept that.

Comment: @DjokerS Look at the main() function I posted. It returns the value returned by QCoreApplication::exec()

Comment: sorry missed that part!