# Test the sucess of a python script that is run by a batch script file

Tags: python, powershell, batch-file

I have a python script that i run via a batch script, at the end i send an email containing a log file and i want to condition my sending emails. if the python script is okay, send an email saying : OK
If the python script failed send the log file.

Comment: Why don't you do it all with PowerShell? Certainly because the method your using to get the date and time in your batch file, are PC/User/Locale dependent.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not well versed in cmd, but in theory, you should check the status code of your python script if its anything other than 0 it failed

[How do I get the application exit code from a Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line)

Comment: Thank you , and what about the email ? Ho can i use the condition ?