# How do I get exit code after running command in integrated terminal in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

After running `terminal.sendtext("some command")`, how do I get the exit code of the command? If this is not possible, is there a way to run the command in external terminal(using something like`child_process.spawnSync()`) and get the exit code?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line

Comment: @EhsanKiani But how can I get that from integrated terminal in an extension?

Comment: I will search and get back to you if I found something useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`);
});

ls.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Reference : https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_close

Comment: This doesn't run in integrated terminal

Answer (score 0):

You could use the new terminal exit api, see [v1.71 Release Notes: terminal exit status api](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_71.md#terminalexitstatusreason):

> #### TerminalExitStatus.reason
>
> Extension authors now have better insight into why a terminal exited
> via the new TerminalExitReason API.

```json
export enum TerminalExitReason {
  Unknown = 0,
  Shutdown = 1,
  Process = 2,
  User = 3,
  Extension = 4,
}
```