# Display program exit status?

Tags: c, gcc, exit-code

if my C program doesn't print out anything, it just returns a value, how can I use gcc to check what value my program returns?
For example,

```
gcc test.c
```

after this I get a a.out, however, if I type "a", nothing will show since my test.c doesn't print anything it just return a value, so how can I check what value my test.c returns?

Comment: Operating system?  Shell?

Comment: If you type `a`, I would expect you to get something along the lines of `a: command not found`.  `a` is not the same as `a.out`.  If you want to know the value returned by main when your program executes from a shell, inspect `$?`

Comment: In Windows: see https://www.shellhacks.com/windows-get-exit-code-errorlevel-cmd-powershell/ ... in bash (and possibly other Un*x shells): `echo $?`

Comment: `%ERRORLEVEL%` on windows command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a typical Linux shell like `bash`, the *exit code* from a program (which is what `main` returns) is stored in the `$?` built-in variable. So if your program returns 42, you can do:

```
$ ./a.out
$ echo $?
42
```

Note that this is 8 bits. It can store a number from 0 to 255. Bigger numbers will wrap around.

On Windows, the variable is called [`%ERRORLEVEL%`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line) (not case-sensitive):

```
C:\> a.exe
C:\> echo %errorlevel%
42
```