# Make Doxygen failure to fail CI/CD on Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, doxygen, cicd

I have a CI/CD pipeline on Gitlab in which I'm generating a Doxygen documentation.
The thing is, even if Doxygen encounters a missing documentation in my code the job is marked as succeeded...

The Doxygen configuration file is as following:

```
EXTRACT_ALL = NO
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC = YES
WARN_AS_ERROR = FAIL_ON_WARNINGS
GENERATE_LATEX = NO
RECURSIVE = YES
```

The CICD itself running on a Docker if that matter.

Thanks!

Comment: As a test you could check in your GitLab workflow what the return status of the doxygen process is. Seen the usage of `WARN_AS_ERROR = FAIL_ON_WARNINGS` I assume you are using a doxygen version >= 1.9.0

Comment: Thank you for you answer friend! can you please tell me how do I check the return status via gitlab?

Comment: No idea how the gitlab workflow works. In a *nix shell I would write  `echo $?` directly after the doxygen call. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line